# How do I implement a generic function from an interface in a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my interface with a generic function:

```
export interface MyInterface  {
    ...
    createTopic: <Type>(message:Type) => any;
    // createTopic: (message:any) => any;
}
```

And this is the class that implents it:

```
export class ClassA implements MyInterface{

    ....

    createTopic<Type extends CustomMessage>(message :CustomMessage ) : CustomResponse{

        this.logger.log(`Created ${message.type} topic.`)
        return {msg: 'messageResponse'};
        
    }
    
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Property 'createTopic' in type 'ClassA' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MyInterface'.
  Type '<Type extends CustomMessage>(message: CustomMessage) => CustomResponse' is not assignable to type '<Type>(message: Type) => any'.
    Types of parameters 'message' and 'message' are incompatible.
      Type 'Type' is not assignable to type 'CustomMessage'.
```

I'm kind of new to typescript so I'm not too sure what the best way is to implement a generic function from an interface is.

Comment: can you explain what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: The error states the problem clearly. `createTopic` as defined in the interface should work for any type but in your case it only works for some. Thus you have violated the constraints of the interface.

Comment: I mean, interfaces are used to make it possible to work with different class implementation using a common information, what it the common information you want to model in your case ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but if you want an interface that receive an **CustomMessage** probably this will help you:

**t** it the costume type you will receive in **createTopic** prop

```
export interface MyInterface<t> {
  createTopic: (message: t) => any;
  // createTopic: (message:any) => any;
}

export interface CustomMessage {
  type: string;
}

export class ClassA implements MyInterface<CustomMessage> {
  createTopic(message: CustomMessage):CustomResponse {
    this.logger.log(`Created ${message.type} topic.`)
    return { msg: 'messageResponse' };
  }
}
```

**Update**

Without passing the type through the interface

```
export interface MyInterface {
  createTopic(message: any): any;
  // createTopic: (message:any) => any;
}

export interface CustomMessage {
  type: string;
}

export interface CustomResponse {
  msg: string;
}

export class ClassA implements MyInterface {
  createTopic(message: CustomMessage): CustomResponse {
    this.logger.log(`Created ${message.type} topic.`);

    // console.log(message.type);
    return { msg: 'messageResponse' };
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear. Maybe I'm just thinking about this wrong but all I want is to make it possible for the createTopic method to be implemented with any type of message format. I see that you are able to achieve it here but I was wondering if it was possible to do this without passing the type through the interface.

Comment: @PeterShepherd check out the update.